# Setting a virtual directory in IIS that points to another server

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual-directory

I added a virtual directory to my website via IIS. The physical path of this directory is located at another server. I added the physical path credentials and gave it a virtual name. the physical path looks like `\\server3\Data\`. 
and the full virtual address is like : `http://audit.iqc.co.il/ReportsApp/` where `ReportsApp` is the virtual directory name.

However, I always get an error that says "URI formats are not supported." when trying to access this directory via my website.

I read somewhere that maybe I should set another application in IIS and then refer to that other app, but I don't know if that the case here.

Comment: Where exactly do you see the error "URI formats are not supported" ? In your browser? In event logs? When trying to save virtual directory configuration in IIS?

Comment: Most probably you have created web application pointing to network folder. What you need to do is first create web application which will point to local directory (may be empty one) and under that application create virtual directory which will point to network folder. That should work however your url will get changed something like http://audit.iqc.co.il/MyApp/ReportsApp

Comment: thanks Pankaj, it seems to do the trick